# PageSheet viewcontroller not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

Have a PageSheet view controller, which is not displaying correctly, the nav bar buttons are over the top of the status bar, this is ugly but usable on most phones but on iPhone X unusable.

[image]

Its an old app that being updated for iPhoneX, this is last issue.

Here it is in designer.

[image]

Displayed like this :-

```
sharedInstance.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

[homeController presentViewController:sharedInstance animated:YES completion:nil];
```

have tried lots of combination of tweaks in designer and code but nothing seems to change the outcome.

Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: Please check below link it might be useful to you stackoverflow.com/a/22565541/5184217

Comment: or you can change the frame of sharedInstance. #define IS_IPHONE_X ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 812.0) if (IS_IPHONE_X) { sharedInstance.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, navigationBarHeight+24, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-navigationBarHeight-24); //24 status bar height  //If naviagtion height getting 0 means add 64 manually}